# Django add brackets to django models field

Tags: python, django

I was trying to add brackets to my django fields how to do it 
Only with brackets there is syntax error

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
Region =models.CharField(max_length=1000,choices=Region, default='-')
Status =models.CharField(max_length=1000,choices=Option, null=True)
APP_SERVER\(Prod\)=models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: \(Prod\) please don't make it had to django... think when you call it out like> Customer.(Prod)?? really?

Comment: or Customer.objects.filter((prod)="abc"). It shouldn't

Comment: "APP_SERVER\(Prod\)" is not a valid python identifier, period. Why would you want to name a field that way anyway ???

Comment: verbose name can be used to change the display name

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost try to follow PEP8 standards for naming variables

From my understanding what you are trying to do is, while seeing in admin / user defined page this field must display `APP_SERVER\(Prod\)` in this format.

For that better to keep you variable name as `app_server`

and while creating `ModelForms` in `forms.py` change the `label`  of the `app_server` field to `APP_SERVER(Prod)`